# Show product after Import

Tags: magento2, import-products

The products after importing does not appear on Magento 2.3 on the front end. But after you click Edit and save  without any modification it show,

Answer (score 0):

Without more info I believe this is an indexing issue

You can do this via command line or admin with extension

https://github.com/magepal/magento2-reindex

Either way you need to get an index into your import workflow

Answer (score 0):

You need reindex Magento store:

a - Reindex from Magento admin

1. Go to **System** > **Index Management** and check indexers status
2. Select the items that are marked as **Reindex required** and go to
   **Actions** > **Update on schedule**

This will trigger a reindex for selected indexers.

b - Reindex via SSH / CLI (recommended)

1. Connect to your Magento 2 installation in the root of your project.
   (usually in public_html )
2. Reindex all Magento 2 indexers using below command

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: hi the problem is not solved

Comment: 1: The products must be Visible in Catalog.
2: The products must be Enabled.
3: Product must have a stock Quantity.
4: The product must be set to In Stock.
5: If the product is set not to track stock, it still has to have a stock Quantity and be set to In Stock.
6: The product must be assigned to the target Category.
7: If using multi-website mode (or if you imported the products through Data Flow), the products must be assigned to the target Website. (check table `catalog_product_website`)
8: You must refresh your Cache / Indices, just to make sure.(`php bin/magento cache:flush
`)